# Why bijection between $\mathbb{N^2}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ is not possible directly?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

To understand bijection between $\mathbb{N^2}$ and
$\mathbb{N}$  I found this pdf on internet. But have couple of confusion.
[image]

**N.B:** Here we take $0 \in \mathbb{N}.$

**Confusion:1** Why directly proof of bijection between $f:\mathbb{N^2}\to\mathbb{N}$  is messy ? But we found easily  one-to-one correspondence $(0, 0)$ and $0, (0, 1)$ and $1, (0, 2)$ and $2.......$so on. That's may be proofs bijection.

**Confusion:2** To prove injective function $f_1:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$, $f_1(n)=(n,0).$ My question is why I define the function in this way,$f_1(n)=(n,0)?$ could I define any function to prove injective like $f_1(n)=(n,1)$ or$f_1(n)=(n,2)$  or $f_1(n)=(1,n)....
.....$ and so on

**Confusion:2** To prove injective function $f_2:\mathbb{N^2}\to\mathbb{N}$, $f_2(n,m)=(2^n,3^m).$My question is why I define the function in this way $f_2(n,m)=(2^n,3^m).$could I define any function to prove injective like $f_2(n,m)=(1^n,3^m),$ or$f_2(n,m)=(2^n,4^m).............$ and so on.

Comment: That text claims that “It's possible to directly construct a bijection $f\colon\Bbb N^2\longrightarrow\Bbb N$”. How did you jump from that to “$f\colon\Bbb N^2\longrightarrow\Bbb N$ directly not possible”?

Comment: As to 2: it's $(n,m) \to 2^n\times 3^m$ so a product in $\Bbb N$, not a pair. Unique prime factorisation gives 1-1-ness. $n \to (n,0)$ because it's an easy to see injection, so no work left.

Comment: The author is too lazy to find a bijection, basically. so [mumble] "details messy.."

Comment: @Henno if I use $2^n×4^m$ then it Will work? If not why?$2^n×4^m$  it also give me 1-1 ness.

Comment: Then $(2,0)$ and $(0,1)$ have the same image $4$ so no injection

Comment: But in first case except  $(n, 0)$ why another will not work? Another $(n, 1), (n, 2)$......will give unique image..

Comment: @Henno "[mumble] "details messy.."  don't understanding. Please explain..

Comment: Yes $$n \to (n,1)$ also works etc. You just have to show one  the mumble remark is a joke, sort of.

Comment: @henno almost understand all confusion. In my question  confusion1 part ,I showed the direct one to one correspondence, it is right?

Comment: [Please do not use images of text, instead of the text itself](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem). It reduces accessibility in several ways.

Comment: No, you did not give a direct bijection; just the first three images; it looks like a projection now, you should give a formula like I did. Or look at the diagonal path bijection e.g.

Comment: @Henno  Not just the first three images and I want to say after that and so on till infinite.

Comment: @Henno could you insert your comments in your answer which will be answer of my 3 confusions, then I will accept the answer.

Comment: I just added some of my comments in the answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The map $(n,m) \to (2n+1)2^m - 1$ is a perfectly valid bijection from $\Bbb N^2$ to $\Bbb N$. (The $-1$ at the end is just to get $0$ as the image of $(0,0)$, etc.)

Confusion 1: the function you sketch ($(0,0) \to 0, (0,1) \to 1, (0,2) \to 2$.... ) is *not* a complete description of a bijection at all, so does not belong in such a proof. It seems more like you're just using the second coordinate of the pair only (a projection in essence) which is *not* a bijection. Where does $(345, 671)$ map to? You don't specify...

Confusion 2: yes, the $0$ second coordinate is arbitrary , $n \to (n,1)$ or $n \to (n,n)$ also works. The author just wants *some* injection that is trivial, 1-1 on sight.

Confusion 3: $(n,m)$ maps to a product in $\Bbb N$, **not** a pair (recall he's defing an injection $\Bbb N^2 \to \Bbb N$ here..) $f(n,m)= 2^n \times 3^m$, which is 1-1 because the number of prime factors $2$ and $3$ that divide a number are uniquely determined (elementary number theory), so we get an injection (not onto as $0$ or $5$ etc are not reached at all as images, just numbers with only factors $2$ or $3$ or both). That's why $1^m \times 2^n$ or $2^m \times 4^n$ do not work as injections. Again, minimal knowledge required to see it's an injection.